# Regex Javascript in order to know if a pattern is containing in a String

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a JavaScript String, for example :

```
var test1 = "aaaaaa@bbbbb.temp" ;  // Function must return true in this case

var test2 = "ccccc@ddddd.fr " ;    // Function must return false in this case
```

I would like to build a function which return true if the String contains @ character, following by any character "bbbbbb" following by ".temp" extension.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `regex#test`

```
var found = /@.*?\.temp\b/.test(str);
```

If you want to make it `@ character, following by "bbbbbb" following by ".temp" extension` then use:

```
var found =  /@bbbbbb\.temp\b/.test(str);
```

Comment: email addresses are case insensitive

Comment: I believe `@.*\.temp$` would be more efficient (`.*` vs `.*?`).

Comment: @sp00m: Probably that is but both of them should work functionally.

Comment: @anubhava Not exactly, yours will match also `a@b.temphello`.

Comment: @sp00m: Oh yes I was more talking from `.* vs .*?` angle. For that I have added `\b` after `\.temp`

Comment: If this answer helped you solve your problem, please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expression solution:

```
function validate(argument) { 
var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    if((argument.lastIndexOf('.temp', argument.length-5)>=argument.length-5) && re.test(argument)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

JsFiddle test: http://jsfiddle.net/2EXxx/

Comment: @M42 just take a look at my code. =\ and don't minus if you even didn't read a code...

Comment: @SimonWhitehead just take a look.

Comment: @M42 and what about this version?

Comment: @M42 Fixed a bit. Accepts only VALID characters for any types of email. BTW in your solution you may replace 'bbbb' with any characters according to the authors question. Anyway thank you for attendion but minus makes me sad (

Comment: OK, I removed my -1. But there're no needs to validate email address in the question. It's just wanted to test if it ends with `.temp`.